# Function of ':' in declaration of variables

Tags: c, include

I have been trying to improve my understanding of C/C++ but looking at includes for functions, such as `printf`, which I use a lot. However I am running across a syntax which I am not familiar with, nor am I able to find.
What does the '`:`' mean? For example:

```
unsigned int is_long_double:1;
```

It seems that it would be some type of precursor to the boolean expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It defines the variable as a bitfield of length 1 bit.

It's only valid in a struct, and only makes sense if you have multiple bitfields together.

Don't use it as a generic boolean because it doesn't save memory - a single bitfield on its own will still take up a full word of memory.

Comment: Makes sense. Knowing that I'm not sure why they bothered with the bool type in c++

Comment: Unless it is in a struct, it causes a syntax error — bit-fields are only allowed within a struct.